# Virtual Column Only Executing for First Row

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to used a function to create a virtual column on my table. The function executes correctly on its own, but when I add to my table:

```
SELECT *, table_a.function FROM table_a;
```

It only executes the function for the first row of the result and gives the same output for all subsequent rows.

Example Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION overnight(table_a)
RETURNS boolean AS
$$
SELECT CASE WHEN (((duration / 60) * 100) + (duration % 60) + departure) >= 2400 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END FROM schema.table_a
$$;
```

How do I ensure the code executes for every row of my table?

Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated but: I would define a column named `duration` as an `interval` and a column named `departure` as `time` rather than (mis)using `integers` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the parameter in your select and get rid of the `FROM` clause (which selects from the *table* not from the row parameter).

To avoid confusion between the table name and the parameter I strongly recommend to use a proper parameter name:

```
CREATE FUNCTION overnight(p_row table_a)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$$
  SELECT (((p_row.duration / 60) * 100) + (p_row.duration % 60) + p_row.departure) >= 2400;
$$
language sql
stable;
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
SELECT *, table_a.function 
FROM table_a;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=917cbde0794c964e8b2fa689db1148a4)

Answer (score 0):

Have your function accept the fields you need, not the whole table.

```
SELECT *, overnight(duration,departure) FROM table_a;

CREATE FUNCTION overnight(duration,departure)
RETURNS boolean AS
SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END;
$$;
```

Comment: Passing the full row (not table!) is perfectly fine